# Can't be able to call after close WebRTC in react-native-webrtc using socket.io

Tags: node.js, react-native, socket.io

I am able to make the initial connection between two devices, but after ending the first call, I am unable to re-connect. I get the following error:

```
Error: Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 9): "peerConnection is null"
```

My code:

```js
const pc_config = {
  "iceServers": [{
      url: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'}]
};
this.localPC = new RTCPeerConnection(pc_config);
// this function call after end call 
endCall = () => {
    console.log(this.socket.id, " reciver ===== caller ", this.reciverid);
    this.socket.emit('callend', {
      socketID: this.reciverid});
    this.state.allUser.map((item) => {
      if (this.socket.id == item.socket_id) {
        Toast.show("Call end by " + item.name);}
    })
    this.localPC.close();
  }
```

Comment: Hi, could you please add the error message as text and not as an image? Thank you

Comment: Hello, this is error message => Error: Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 9):
"peerConnection is null"

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: @oldgreg, did you get any solution ?